# Selecting different row-column combinations in tab_footnote locations for gt package in R

Tags: r, windows, gt

Is there a way to select different rows per column for the same footnote in the gt package in R?

```
df = data.frame(Indicators = c("P1","P2","P3","P4","P5"), 
                Grp1 = c(3,2,1,1,4), 
                Grp2 = c(3,4,4,2,2), 
                Grp3 = c(1,1,2,1,4))

  Indicators Grp1 Grp2 Grp3
1         P1    3    3    1
2         P2    2    4    1
3         P3    1    4    2
4         P4    1    2    1
5         P5    4    2    4
```

I have a reference table for the cells (column names and row numbers) where the footnote should appear.

```
lookup <- data.frame(grp = c("Grp2","Grp2","Grp3"),
                     rows = c(2,4,1))

   grp rows
1 Grp2    2
2 Grp2    4
3 Grp3    1
```

How can I use the lookup table in the `locations` argument for `tab_footnote` properly?

The code below returns a table with a footnote for the same rows for `Grp2` and `Grp3` instead of only rows 2 and 4 for `Grp2` and row 1 for `Grp3`.

```
df %>% 
    gt() %>% 
    tab_footnote(footnote = "Corrected value", 
                 locations = cells_body(columns = lookup$grp, rows = lookup$rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a manual way, but here a solution:

```
df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_footnote(footnote = "Corrected value", 
               locations = cells_body(columns = c(Grp2,Grp2), rows = c(2,4) )) %>% 
  tab_footnote(footnote = "Corrected value", 
               locations = cells_body(columns = Grp3, rows = c(1)))
```

[image]

Comment: May i ask if I have multiple footnotes, is it possible to set them on same row?